# Are magento upgrades acumulative?

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, magento1.9.3.1

I want to upgrade magento from 1.9.2.1 to 1.9.3.1

**Can I upgrade to 1.9.3.1 in one go by selecting "upgrade to 1.9.3.1"** or shoud I upgrade incrementially (1.9.2.2, 1.9.2.3,1.9.2.4, 1.9.3.0, 1.9.3.0 and finally 1.9.3.1) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It used to be so painful that it was semi incremental (back in the days, it was recommended to upgrade from 1.3 to 1.5 then to 1.9).

Between 1.9 versions, you can totally upgrade from 1.9.2.1 to 1.9.3.1 but I suggest you do a backup first and make some tests on a dev server as some modules may not be compatible with the last version.

Comment: Thank you very much for you prompt reply, this will save me a lot of time.